# Mysql join on 3 tables output

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am learning joins and have the following tables.

Student

```
| ID | NAME |
-------------
|  1 |    A |
|  2 |    B |
|  3 |    C |
|  4 |    D |
```

Pass

```
| ID | MARKS |
--------------
|  2 |    80 |
|  3 |    75 |
```

Fail

```
| ID | MARKS |
--------------
|  1 |    25 |
|  4 |    20 |
```

The output I want is this:

```
| NAME | MARKS |
----------------
|    B |    80 |
|    C |    75 |
|    A |    25 |
|    D |    20 |
```

I wrote a query like this:

```
select s.id,s.name,p.marks from student s 
left join pass p on s.id=p.id 
left join  (select f.marks,f.id from fail f ) as nn on s.id=nn.id 
order by marks desc;
```

The output I got is this:

```
| id | name | Marks| 
--------------------
| 1  |   B  |  80  |
| 2  |   C  |  75  |
| 3  |   A  | Null |
| 4  |   D  | NUll |
```

Cant figure out why Null is coming. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CASE` statement for that:

```
SELECT Name,
CASE WHEN P.Marks IS NULL THEN f.Marks ELSE P.Marks END AS Marks
FROM Student s
LEFT JOIN Pass p ON s.ID = p.ID
LEFT JOIN Fail f ON s.ID = f.ID
ORDER BY Marks DESC;
```

Or you can also use `IF` statement:

```
SELECT Name,
IF(P.Marks IS NULL, F.Marks, P.Marks) AS Marks
FROM Student s
LEFT JOIN Pass p ON s.ID = p.ID
LEFT JOIN Fail f ON s.ID = f.ID
ORDER BY Marks DESC;
```

Output

```
| NAME | MARKS |
----------------
|    B |    80 |
|    C |    75 |
|    A |    25 |
|    D |    20 |
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/86a51/12)

To learn more about JOINs see: [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below Query, use **[COALESCE](http://forums.hscripts.com/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=2589)**

```
select s.id,s.name,COALESCE(p.marks , nn.marks) as marks
from student s 
left join pass p on s.id=p.id 
left join fail nn on s.id=nn.id 
order by marks desc;
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/86a51/15)**

Comment: Coalesce(p.marks, nn,marks) as markks and then order by markss desc . Else it gave error like marks ambiguous..

Answer (score 0):

You select only the passed marks, this is the reason of null-s appears near falied results.
If you want to select the failed marks you can use `IF` condition

```
select s.id,s.name,IF(p.marks = null, nn.marks, p.marks) as markss
from student s 
left join pass p on s.id=p.id 
left join fail nn on s.id=nn.id 
order by markss desc;
```

Or you can use `union` of the passed and failed results.

```
select s.id,s.name, u.marks
from student s 
left join ( (SELECT * FROM pass) UNION (SELECT * FROM fail) ) as n ON n.id = s.id
order by marks desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how the different joins work to understand why you receive `NULL` for the `marks` column.
Take a look here:[A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

The relevant example for you is:

LEFT OUTER JOIN:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB
ON TableA.name = TableB.name

id  name       id    name
--  ----       --    ----
1   Pirate     2     Pirate
2   Monkey     null  null
3   Ninja      4     Ninja
4   Spaghetti  null  null
```

[image]

- The Null values you received for the `marks` column are rows that have no match in the left joined tables.
- (the left part of the Venn diagram) the values that does have a value are the cross section between the tow groups of the Venn Diagram.

specifics for your example:

```
select s.id,s.name,p.marks 
from student s 
left join pass p on s.id=p.id 
left join  (select f.marks,f.id from fail f ) as nn on s.id=nn.id 
order by marks desc;
The output i got is this:

id | name | Marks
-------------------
1  |  B   | 80
2  |  C   | 75
3  |  A   | Null
4  |  D   | NUll
```

This will return all student rows when.

- students that have a passing gtade will display the grade and thous who don't will display null.